# How can I search/filter a specific data in my table?

Tags: php, html, mysql

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
    <head>
      <title>Pre-Enrollment</title>
      <meta charset="utf-8">
      <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
      <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/bootstrap.css">
      <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/custom.css">
    </head>

    <nav>
        <ul class="nav nav-tabs">
            <li role="presentation" class="active"><a href="FromEnrollment.php">Pre-Enrollment</a></li>
            <li role="presentation"><a href="Students.php">Students</a></li>
            <li role="presentation"><a href="Subjects.php">Subjects</a></li>
        </ul>
    </nav>
    <br>
    <br>
    <body>
        <div class="container">
            <div class="row">
                    <div class="col-md-4">
                        <form id="idNumber" action="#">
                        <div class="input-group">
                            <input type="text" class="form-control" placeholder="ID NUMBER">
                            <span class="input-group-btn">
                                <button class="btn btn-default" type="button">Enter</button>
                                <button class="btn btn-default" type="button" onclick="resetIdNumber()" value="reset">Reset</button>     
                            </span>
                        </div>
                        </form>
                    </div>
                    <div class="col-md-4 col-md-offset-4">
                        <select style="width: 120px;">
                            <option value="All">Overall Term</option>
                            <option value="First">First Term</option>
                            <option value="Second">Second Term</option>
                            <option value="Short">Short Term</option>
                        </select>
                    </div>
            </div>
            <br>
            <div class="row">
                    <div class="col-md-6">
                        <p> NAME:</p>
                    </div>
                    <div class="col-md-4">
                       <p> Course and Year: </p>
                    </div>
            </div>
            <br>
            <div class="row">
                <div class="col-md-6">
                    <form id="Subjects" action="#">
                    <div class="input-group">
                        <input type="text" class="form-control" placeholder="Search for...">
                        <span class="input-group-btn">
                            <button class="btn btn-default" type="button">Enter</button>
                            <button class="btn btn-default" type="button" onclick="resetSubjects()" value="reset">Reset</button>
                        </span>
                    </div>
                    </form>
                </div>
            </div>
            <br>

            <?php
            include 'dbcon.php';
            $stmt = $pdo->query("SELECT coursenumber as 'Course No.', destitle as 'Descriptive Title', units as 'Units' FROM subjects");
            ?>

            <div class="row">
                    <div class="col-md-6 col">  
                        <table class="table">
                            <tr>
                                <th>Course No.</th>
                                <th>Descriptive Title</th>
                                <th>Unit</th>
                                <th></th>
                            </tr>

                            <?php
                            $results = $stmt->fetchAll(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);
                            foreach ($results as $row) {
                                    echo "<tr>";
                                    echo "<td>".$row['Course No.']."</td>";
                                    echo "<td>".$row['Descriptive Title']."</td>";
                                    echo "<td>".$row['Units']."</td>";
                                    echo "<td> <button class='btn btn-default' type='button'> <span class='glyphicon glyphicon-plus' aria-hidden='true'></span></button></td>";
                                    echo "</tr>";
                            }
                            ?>
                        </table>
                    </div>
                    <div class="col-md-6">
                        <table class="table">
                            <tr>
                                <th>Course No.</th>
                                <th>Descriptive Title</th>
                                <th>Unit</th>
                                <th>Term</th>
                                <th></th>
                            </tr>
                        </table>
                        <button class="button" type="button" value="apply">Apply</button>
                    </div>
            </div>
            </div>
        <script>
            function resetIdNumber(){
                document.getElementById("idNumber").reset();
            }
            function resetSubjects(){
                document.getElementById("Subjects").reset();
            }
        </script>

        <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.2.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
        <script src="js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
        </body>

</html>
```

I have successfully displayed my database in an html table using the php code. Now I want to filter/search for a specific data in my table using my placeholder. Is there any way to do it with my code?

Comment: What happens when you run your code?

Comment: I'm confused by the question - it looks like you are already using the database content to build an html table

Comment: Certainly there is a way. How do you think all those internet pages could work otherwise? Question here is: since you already use code to retrieve values from a database and output those, why don't you simply place them in a html table? You currently output table rows and cells, but you forgot to open and close the table itself!

Comment: it inputs the data in my database as html table.

Comment: So you want to append the new rows to your existing table?

Comment: Im currently working in a pre-enrollment app right now, I wanted to transfer the data in another table for verification purposes only. Then I will submit those transferred data in my database as finished output. But I was stuck in transferring those data in another table.

Comment: This is confusing: do you want to fill an HTML table as you stated in the title and question or a database table as you now say here in the comments?

Comment: Can we see all your code? Your PDO instance and you SQL query. Also, think about avoiding space in your database fields.

Answer (score 0):

> I wanted to transfer the data in another table for verification
>   purposes only

If it's only for verification purposes, why not use PHP [validate filters](http://php.net/manual/en/filter.filters.validate.php) and/or [sanitize filters](http://php.net/manual/en/filter.filters.sanitize.php) once you're at it.

- Validating data = Determine if the data is in proper form.
- Sanitizing data = Remove any illegal character from the data.

You could use the following code just to check if the`Course No.` is an `INT` and it's value:

```
$result = filter_var($row['Course No.'], FILTER_VALIDATE_INT);
var_dump($result);
```

Example for sanitizing data:

```
$newDescprTitle = filter_var($row['Descriptive Title'], FILTER_SANITIZE_STRING);
echo $newDescprTitle;
```

[More on filters](https://www.w3schools.com/php/php_filter.asp)

I guess this is a better and safer method than just copying the same data to another table before transferring them to a database.

Let me know if this was of any use.
If you're planning on continuing with your method I'll look futher into that.

**UPDATE**

It seems you're getting the data succesfull and put them in a table like this:

```
                        <table class="table">
                        <tr>
                            <th>Course No.</th>
                            <th>Descriptive Title</th>
                            <th>Unit</th>
                            <th></th>
                        </tr>

                        <?php
                        $results = $stmt->fetchAll(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);
                        foreach ($results as $row) {
                                echo "<tr>";
                                echo "<td>".$row['Course No.']."</td>";
                                echo "<td>".$row['Descriptive Title']."</td>";
                                echo "<td>".$row['Units']."</td>";
                                echo "<td> <button class='btn btn-default' type='button'> <span class='glyphicon glyphicon-plus' aria-hidden='true'></span></button></td>";
                                echo "</tr>";
                        }
                        ?>
                    </table>
```

For the transfer to the other table, I made a snippet, is this what you were looking for?

```js
function AddData() {
  var course = document.getElementById('course').innerText;
  var descrp = document.getElementById('descrp').innerText;
  var unit = document.getElementById('unit').innerText;
  var term = document.getElementById('term').innerText;

  document.getElementById('opcourse').innerHTML = course;
  document.getElementById('opdescrp').innerHTML = descrp;
  document.getElementById('opunit').innerHTML = unit;
  document.getElementById('opterm').innerHTML = term;
}
```

```css
th,
td {
  padding-right: 5em;
  text-align: left;
}
```

```html
<link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<body>
  <div class="col-md-6 col">
    <table class="table">
      <tr>
        <th>Course No.</th>
        <th>Descriptive Title</th>
        <th>Unit</th>
        <th>Term</th>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td id="course">1</td>
        <td id="descrp">Ceci n'est pas un descriptive title</td>
        <td id="unit">unit no. 5</td>
        <td id="term">first term</td>
        <td>
        <button class='btn btn-default' type='button' onclick="AddData()"> <span class='glyphicon glyphicon-plus' aria-hidden='true'></span></button>
        </td>
      </tr>
    </table>
  </div>
  <br>
  <div class="col-md-6">
    <table class="table" id="copy">
      <thead>
        <tr>
          <th>Course No.</th>
          <th>Descriptive Title</th>
          <th>Unit</th>
          <th>Term</th>
          <th></th>
        </tr>
      </thead>
      <td id="opcourse"></td>
      <td id="opdescrp"></td>
      <td id="opunit"></td>
      <td id="opterm"></td>
    </table>
  </div>
</body>
```